# how do i run VSCode Debug on python venv?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a problem which vscode can run debug when i select python which installed in global environment but can't run debug when i select python which installed in venv. Have anyone know how to fix it ?

I listed my info. as below:

- [default and venv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7kvW.png)
- [launch.json of .vscode folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wTSV.png)
- [settings.json of .vscode folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6CcY.png)
- [project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFzNA.png)

  - the hello.py only print("Hello world")
- By the way, i have activate my venv already. e.g. (venv) D:\hello_flask_test>

Comment: You will have to share the error as debugging when having a virtual environment works for me.

Comment: The question is that debugging isn't stopped in any break point i set

Comment: It's seem that it doesn't get the setting of venv

Comment: Set `python.pythonPath` to point to the Python interpreter in your virtual environment, then the extension will pick up your virtual environment.